# Magento 2 Commerce Question : What is the use of MAGEID and TOKEN in Magento 2 Commerce and How we can use it installing the extension

Tags: magento2.3

I am new to Magento Commerce 2.3.4 and need to understand the use of MAGEID and TOKEN generated by the Magento account. I have the MAGEID and TOKEN but I don't know how and where to update this token in Magento file/database.

Also how I can use the TOKEN while installing any extension or downloading a release?

Answer (score 0):

So you've got your keys as shown here

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html

Magento comes with a sample file in your root as `auth.json.sample` you need to copy it to `auth.json`

It contains 2 key sets: 1 for Github and 1 for the Magento Repo

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Enter the following data to your `auth.json` file to login. Please use the Public Key and the Private Key

```
    {
        "http-basic": {
            "repo.magento.com": {
                "username":"<your public key>",
                "password":"<your private key>"
            }
        }
    }
```

With these in place you can then install components using composer. Run this from web root.

`composer install`

Comment: This is something you have told about using repo's public and private keys. But I need more information about this link - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using open source edition don't worry about MAGEID

> For access to Magento Commerce and Magento Commerce Cloud packages, you must use keys associated with a MAGEID that has been granted access to those packages. If you encounter errors, you may not be authorized to access the package. Contact Magento support for assistance with your MAGEID.

Comment: No. I am not using the open-source edition. I have configured the enterprise edition on my local machine but I need to configure the MAGEID and the TOKEN to install the packages. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What are you trying to install? What have you tried?

Comment: I am now to commerce edition and wants to know the use of MAGEID and TOKEN mentioned here - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html#manage-ssh-access-token

Also is it necessary to use MAGEID and TOKEN while installing any extension or release download?